# Pattern matching and identifying the pattern type

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to use some lookup data that we have but without much explanation of how the patterns are to be used.  Looks similar to a regex string, but with some extra chars that make them invalid and cause errors trying to use them as regex patterns to match on.

eg. The list of patterns to check:

```
ABHH9***113+
GYER0-08G
DVTYYT53***
```

The strings to be used to check against the patterns would be product name codes.
For example something like this:

```
DVTYYT53A12
DVTYYT53A33
ABHHYUU11344
```

What sort of pattern matching could be performed if I have a list of name strings and a list of patterns to search and for each name, I need to see if I have a match in the list of pattern strings.

However, when using this expression "DVTYYT53***" as a regex pattern, the extra two * characters cause problems.  This leads me to think that these "pattern" strings we have are not regular expressions, but some other form of patterns, or some regex alternative?

Just to be clear,  at present, the pattern "DVTYYT53***" would mean DVTYYT53 followed by any 3 but at least 3 characters

[update]
These patterns are wildcards, so assume * = any alpha-numeric character, + = anything that includes the preceeding characters

Comment: Not Regex. Looks more like * means any single char and + means any number of chars or greater than. Custom perhaps?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your patterns, I don't think any of the examples you've provided would fit the patterns. Or does *** mean any length (in the case of DVT...)?

Comment: Problem is that I dont control the "patterns" we have been given.  So at present, the pattern "DVTYYT53***" would mean DVTYYT53 followed by any 3 but at least 3 characters.

Comment: "*but at least 3 characters*" ? this seems suspicious and ambiguous.

Comment: Oh, well if you know the rules then these definitely aren't regex. In regex "any 3 but at least 3" is `.{3,}` or `...+`. They don't conform to anything I recognise and hence I'd vote that they're a bespoke implementation. Decompile the program that uses them and look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can determine a suitable replacement for each of the non-standard patterns to convert to regex then you could use this kind of approach:

```
var patterns = new[] { "ABHH***113+", "GYER0-08G", "DVTYYT53***" };
var codes = new[] { "DVTYYT53A12", "DVTYYT53A33", "ABHHYUU11344" };

var pattern2regex = new[]
{
    new { pattern = "*", regex = "." },
    new { pattern = "+", regex = ".+?" },
    new { pattern = "-", regex = ".*?" },
};

var results =
    from pattern in patterns
    let regex = pattern2regex.Aggregate(pattern, (a, x) => a.Replace(x.pattern, x.regex))
    from code in codes
    where Regex.IsMatch(code, regex)
    orderby code, pattern
    select new { code, pattern };
```

That gives me:

[image: results]

Please note that I changed your pattern `ABHH9***113+` to `ABHH***113+` to give a more complete result.

Answer (score 1):

If I was given this task, I'd approach it in two steps.

*1 Get the Spec for the Patterns*

The patterns that you have been given don't conform to any well known standards.

One options would be to go to the source of these patterns, and ask what they mean. If that isn't possible, you could try to reverse engineer them by looking at lots of examples, and figuring out what all the special characters mean.

*2 Use the Patterns*

Once you've figured out what the patterns mean, you can match them in one of several ways.

First, you could try to convert them into a regex. For example, you could use a regex to find a group of '*' characters, count how many you have, and then swap it for an equivalent regex.

An alternative is to write your own matching code, which loops through the strings one character at a time and checks them against the patterns, implementing the rules as appropriate.

*Coding*

It isn't really possible to help with step 2 until we have a clear answer to step 1.